# Write Element one by one into a xml List

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb

I have a requirement where I need to make a report like below

```
<ReportName>

<ReportHeader>
<HeaderData1>data1</HeaderData1>
<HeaderData2>data2</HeaderData2>
</ReportHeader>

<StudentList>

<Student>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>name1</Name>
<Age>22</Age>
</Student>

<Student>
<Id>2</Id>
<Name>name3</Name>
<Age>32</Age>
</Student>

</StudentList>
<ReportName>
```

I need to read from different sources and then add these students object in  StudentList,
One approach is I create this whole object and marshall it to output file,

But I don't Want to make these whole object in memory, at one time and then marshall JaxB.
As file size can be very large.
How can I marshall them one student object at a time to output XML file

Comment: You can't using a well formed xml.  A well formed xml contains only one tag at root layer and saving the xml will add the closing tag and then you will not be able to add additional data.  Most people will use a Non Well formed XML which contains an array of elements at the root.